# Can I create two questions on a similar topic in a row?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I just created this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50211583/how-to-block-a-single-datatable-cell-in-primefaces-with-blockui), asking basically for "How to do X in a table cell". I also would like to know, "How to do X in a table column". (Mentioned it in the comments)

The answers could be very similar, or could be completely different (i.e impossible to do for cells, but you can do it for columns).

I see two possible courses of action, and I think both have their downsides:

1. Create both questions. This feels like spamming very similar questions which is annoying.
2. Don't create the second question. I think the second question is one that people might also have in the future, so it's a loss not to have it on the site.

So which behaviour would you encourage?

Comment: What's wrong with asking both things in the same question—so long as they are closely related? ("How would I do X in a table cell? And would that differ from doing X in a table column?")

Answer (score 9):

I don't think it is a good idea to post almost the same question twice in a very short time frame. That might be considered abusive by the community you are posting in.

I would:

- Ask question 1;
- Wait for some time to gather answers;
- If you have an answer, test if it works for question 2 too;
- If not, ask a new question and link question 1. Explain why the solution for 1 didn't help for question 2.

Comment: good point, I didn't consider the possibility of just waiting and seeing if the other question would be worth asking